# Getting rid of polygons and lines within polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I wanted to create features for all the streets in my area and I did so by differentiating parcel data over my boundary. I got what I wanted but it looks like it also grabbed the small slivers between parcels. I do not want these. How do I go about cleaning this up? I can't delete the small polygons as it is all one single feature.

[See images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am6FF.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have gaps that appear as slivers. I would experiment with Union, NO_GAPS option. If you have actual Slivers then Dissolve or Eliminate will fix them.